# And query for Activerecord has_many relations with array argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I need to make and query with has_many relation model.

I have following tables.  Articles has has_many relation to tags.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tags
end


class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :article
end
```

For example, I would like to get articles contains "BBQ" and "Pork"

I have following code but it return articles contains "BBQ" or "Pork"

```
tags = ["BBQ", "Pork"] # number of items could be any

Article.joins(:tags).where(tags: { tag_name: tags } )
```

Edit:

We don't know how many items in tags.

tag_name field is String.

Comment: What format is the tag_name field in? Array? String?

Comment: tag_name field is String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first get all the tag records that are BBQ like so:

```
Tag.where(tag_name:"BBQ")
```

Then from those, I would add all the tag records that have tag_name Pork:

```
Tag.where(tag_name:"BBQ") + Tag.where(tag_name:"Pork")
```

Then in order to the the articles that they belong to, I would take the combined array and append `.articles`.

So my final search would be:

```
(Tag.where(tag_name:"BBQ") + Tag.where(tag_name:"Pork")).articles
```

**Note on database structure**

My guess is that you want to have two tables, one for all the tags used on your site, and one for the articles. You want each article to possibly have multiple tags. If thats the case, then it might make more sense to make a join table instead of just having the two, because that would mean that a tag could belong to multiple articles and and multiple articles could belong to a tag. To do that, you would add a table:

```
create_table :article_tags do |i|
    i.integer :article_id
    i.integer :tag_id
end
```

In that case, you could have a simpler query.

Comment: Using join table seems a better solution, I'll try this

Comment: I'll write a query when I get a sec, for now look at the rails docs for has_many through. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 3):

It's not that pretty  but you could try

```
Article.joins(:tags).where(tags: { tag_name: "BBQ" } ).where(tags: {tag_name: "Pork"})
```

If you need something more reusable you can create a scope such as "by_tag_name":

```
Article.rb
    scope :by_tag_name, ->(name) { where(tags: {tag_name: name} }
```

And use it simply like:

```
Article.joins(:tags).by_tag_name("BBQ").by_tag_name("Pork")
```

If tags is of unknown size:

```
@articles_with_tags = Article.joins(:tags)

#assume tags is a regular ruby array ["Pork", "Soy Sausages"]
tags.each do |tag| 
    @articles_with_tags = @articles_with_tags.by_tag_name(tag)
end
```

Comment: @Bigair I edited the answer for a possible solution . However it will make n queries for n tags , which should be reasonable if a post has 1-10 tags.

Comment: Does the third example iterates array by ruby or it uses sql?  Wouldn't iterating array by ruby make the request slower?

Comment: @Bigair No , why do you think that ?It's perfectly reasonable to write ruby code, even array iterations! Also remember that Rails is built on Ruby, if it couldn't perform an array iteration in a reasonable time we would all be in big trouble. Unless the array is unusually large you have nothing to worry about.